# Image with line, curls and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

Wants to draw an image given in the attachment. Any advice ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) coordinate[pos=0.66] (x1) coordinate[pos=.1](y1);
\draw[green!50!black] (x1) -- ++(6,0) coordinate (x2) coordinate[pos={1/3}] (p1)
    coordinate[pos={2/3}] (p2);
\draw (0,0 -|x2) -- (0,2 -|x2) coordinate[pos=.1](y2);
\draw[latex-latex] (y1) -- (y2) node[fill=white,midway]{$\mathsf{l_i}$};
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\draw (p\X) -- ++(0,-0.2);
\draw (p\X) -- (0,2 -| p\X) coordinate[midway] (q\X) node[above]
{$\mathsf{Pt_\X}$};}
\draw [latex-latex] (q1) -- (q2)
node[fill=white,midway]{$\mathsf{T^*}$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (0,0 |- q1) -- (q1)
node[midway,above=2pt]{$\mathsf{T^\#}$};
\draw[red,dashed,-latex] (p2) to[out=-150,in=-30] (p1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Fixed stupid c & p error.